# Non-breaking space between long and short form of acronyms with glossaries/glossaries-extras

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I would like to enforce non-breaking spaces between the long and short form of acronyms with `glossaries`/`glossaries-extras`. I stumbled across [this blog post](http://bastian.rieck.me/blog/posts/2016/latex_glossaries/) where the author uses the following command in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\acrfullformat}[2]{#1~(#2)}
```

However, this doesn't work with my setup:

```
\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\glsdisablehyper
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\loadglsentries{resources/acronyms}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tip (unrelated to problem): although you can explicitly have `\usepackage{glossaries}` before `\usepackage{glossaries-extra}` it's better to leave `glossaries-extra` to load `glossaries` implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\acrfullformat` is provided with the base `glossaries` acronym styles. The `glossaries-extra` extension package uses a different abbreviation mechanism, which is much more flexible. The `long-short` style uses `\glsxtrfullsep{`*label*`}` as the separator between the long form and the parenthetical short form. This is simply defined as:

```
\newcommand*{\glsxtrfullsep}[1]{\space}
```

(The label is provided as an argument in case some customisation is required, such as if you want to measure the short or long form to determine whether or not a non-breakable space might be appropriate or have a different separator for a particular category.)

So you just need to redefine this command to use a non-breakable space instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-acronym}% dummy entries

\begin{document}
Some filler, filler, filler, filler, filler, filler, filler, filler text \gls{lid}.

\glsresetall
\renewcommand{\glsxtrfullsep}[1]{~}

Some filler, filler, filler, filler, filler, filler, filler, filler text \gls{lid}.
\end{document}
```

[image: image of sample document]